# UITableViewCell contentView subview presented with offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I added small `UIView` at beginning of `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView` (`width = 6px`, `height = cell.frame.size.height`) - this is added in storyboard.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I reach that view via `tag = 9` and set its background color (dynamic).

```
    UIView *colorView = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:9];
    UIColor *color = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        // Category section - add colors here

        // Get color view
        color = [UIColor colorForCategory:[NewsCategory categoryForString:cellTitle]];

    } else
    {
        color = nil;
    }

    [colorView setBackgroundColor:color];
```

That works fine but as `indexpath.row` is bigger (we go down in `tableView`) that colored view is being offset more and more down (y) where last cell is overlapped by few pixels of above's cell's color view. Dunno why that happening and its not that obvious until you press cell and new colored view is presented...

Comment: Have you tried using Autolayout to position your `colorView` in IB?

Comment: You need to show us the code where you actually add the subview.

Comment: Adding is via storyboard... And I used autolayout

Comment: Well, obviously the code you posted is not responsible for shifting your `UIView` down, because it only sets the color. So either it has to do something with Autolayout/Autoresizing or at some other point in your code you set the color view's frame (maybe even as a side effect of some other method).